# looping mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Okay, so basically, i want to loop mysql_fetch_array inside a foreach loop, like this:

```
    foreach($groupname as $group)
    {
        $sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE group='$group'");
        $row2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
        ?>
        <img src="images/groups/" width="100px" height="100px" /><br />
        <table>
        <tr><td><b>Group: </b></td><td><?php echo $group; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td><b>Description: </b></td><td><?php echo $row2['description']; ?></td></tr>
        </table><br /><br /><br />
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

So when i do that, i get the following mysql error:

```
  Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...
```

Any way around this?

**Note:** Before i do the foreach loop, i do a while loop where i loop through a mysql table, which actually succeed. this is the code snippet for the while loop:

```
    $groupname=array();
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM joined WHERE email='$email'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $groupname[]=$row['group'];
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Just FYI, the entire `mysql` set of functions will be deprecated in PHP 5.5. You should teach yourself `mysqli` to stay current.

Comment: lol, forgot to ask the question xD
And thanks for the tip DevlshOne

Comment: @ahmad albayati: `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: @zerkms Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group='test'' at line 1

Comment: Possible duplicate [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11674313/250259) for how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check for errors using `mysql_error()` ie.

```
$sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE `group`='$group'") or die(mysql_error());
```

but it is failing as `group` is a reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html
use backticks around `group` -

```
SELECT * FROM groups WHERE `group`='$group'
```

Answer (score 1):

`group` is a [mysql keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) so you need to enclose it in backticks:

```
WHERE `group` = ...
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. That fixed the error. My bad. Should have guessed that :P

Comment: @ahmad albayati: don't guess - just use `mysql_error`. It stated it clearly